# Parameter is not correct in python

Tags: python

```
import os
import linecache
gg = "C:\Users\gnk.n\Desktop\stg"
os.system('dir /s' +gg+ '>> gadt11110.txt')
with open("C:\Users\gnk\Desktop\scripts\gadt11110.txt") as f:
    nofolines = len(f.readlines())
    Fileline = nofolines -1
    liness = linecache.getline("C:\Users\gnk\Desktop\scripts\gadt11110.txt", Fileline)
    print liness
```

In the above code what is wrong, when i ran getting parameter is wrong. Pls help
Error:Parameter format not correct - "sC:\Users\gnk\Desktop\stg".

Comment: are you missing a space after /s ?

Comment: a) There is no space between `/s` and the path b) always use a raw string (`r"…"`) if you have a backslash in a string.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Use a raw string literal when referencing file paths on Windows (which contain '\' chars).  A raw string literal looks like a regular string, but has the letter 'r' in front, like `r"C:\Users\..."`.

Comment: Yes. missed space. Thank you all. It's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `os.system('dir /s' +gg+ '>> gadt11110.txt')` to `os.system('dir /s ' +gg+ '>> gadt11110.txt')`.

Note the added space after `dir /s`.

You may also run into issues not escaping your `\` characters.

Comment: If this answered your question please select it as the accepted answer.